# for sequelize js findall

Tags: javascript, for-loop, sequelize.js

Why does my cycle findall once.
More precisely, it outputs only one record from the base

it picks me the first entry and that's it

```
const task = cron.schedule('* * * * *', async () => {
    try {
        let u_sers = await User.findAll();
        for (let i = 0; u_sers.length; i++) {
          
        }
        console.log('running a task every minute');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, please try to provide a minimal reproducible example. You have an empty loop and there is no indication of what is the expected vs observed behavior. This makes hard for other people to help you in understanding what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should correct the `for` condition:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < u_sers.length; i++) {

}
```

And of course you can check `u_sers.length` and output it to the console to make sure you have more than one record.
I'd recommend to use `for of` for such cases as a safer alternative:

```js
for (const user of u_sers) {

}
```